# Why does adding if clause to the query result with if error?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL server, script.

Problem comes with if-then clause syntax.

Having an issue writing an SQL query.

The idea is to do the following: if someone has all three *name-s, then the fname should be a concat of three columns.

In case a customer does not have second name, the concat only takes surname and name columns (for better representation).

The issue is that pgAdmin gives error: "ERROR:  ERROR:  syntax error (: "if")
LINE 1: if ("

Could you please assist with the mentioned problem?

```
if (
    select second_name from bank.person is NULL)
then (
    select concat(name,' ',surname) as fname, age
        from bank.person sp
            where creation_date = (select max(creation_date) from bank.person) 
            or creation_date = (select min(creation_date) from bank.person);)
else (
    select concat(name,' ',second_name,' ',surname) as fname, age
        from bank.person sp
            where creation_date = (select max(creation_date) from bank.person) 
            or creation_date = (select min(creation_date) from bank.person);)
end if;
```

Comment: There's several things wrong with that code. For starters the condition for `IF` doesn't make sense unless `person` only ever contains one record. The there's the context missing. In what environment do you execute this? In a function/procedure? Then show the rest of the code. You also cannot do a `SELECT` without a target there.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have IF clauses, but it does have CASE expressions which can be used to do the same thing in many cases.  I think you are confusing SQL itself with a procedural language, like [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html), into which you can embed SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an IF for that, just use `concat_ws()` - it properly deals with NULL values and empty strings.

```
select concat_ws(' ', name, second_name, surname) as fname, 
       age
from bank.person 
where creation_date = (select max(creation_date) from bank.person) 
   or creation_date = (select min(creation_date) from bank.person);
```

Note that you can combine the two sub-selects into one, making the query a bit more efficient.

---

```
select concat_ws(' ', p.name, p.second_name, p.surname) as fname, 
       p.age
from bank.person p
   join (
       select max(creation_date) as max_date, 
              min(creation_date) as min_date
       from bank.person
   ) t on p.creation_date in (t.max_date, t.min_date);
```